# Is it normal to be on :dev env when running mix test?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I am experiencing an issue where my `test/support` past is not getting compiled:

```
  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib"]
```

I decided to check the environment when running `mix test` and to my surprise its `:dev`

```
pry(1)> Mix.env()
:dev
```

Am I missing some additional configuration?

mix file:

```
defmodule ProjectWeb.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :project,
      version: "0.1.0",
      build_path: "../../_build",
      config_path: "../../config/config.exs",
      deps_path: "../../deps",
      lockfile: "../../mix.lock",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
      elixir: "~> 1.6",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help compile.app" to learn about applications.
  def application do
    [
      extra_applications: [:logger],
      mod: {ProjectWeb.Application, []}
    ]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:dev), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib"]

  # Run "mix help deps" to learn about dependencies.
  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.3.3"},
      {:pre_plug, "~> 1.0"},
      {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.1", only: :dev}
    ]
  end

end
```

Comment: It is incredibly hard to tell whether you are missing some _additional_ configuration when you have not shared your _existing_ config. `mix test` should set an environment to `:test` in a default configuration.

Comment: There is my current mix file, notice I modified the  defp elixirc_paths(:dev), do: ["lib", "test/support"] to make it work

Comment: I have also a config/test.exs file with just use Mix.Config

Comment: The file looks ok. Could you try to `IO.puts Mix.env` from your `config.exs` instead of dealing with `pry`. Honestly, I am not sure if either `iex` or `pry` does not set the environment on it’s own.

Comment: well I found the issue, if you have set the env variable MIX_ENV=dev it will still be :dev even using mix test

Comment: Of course it will; it’s intended behaviour, allowing you to preserve the better control  of the environment, rather than implied by `mix` itself.